# Grails layoutResources equivalent for asset-pipeline

Tags: grails, resources, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to setup a SiteMesh layout in grails v2.3.1 using the [asset-pipeline plug-in](http://grails.org/plugins/asset-pipeline) (v1.0.4), but I'm not sure how to handle inclusion of javascript resources in a specific location of my template (like you would using r:layoutResources if using the [resources plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/resources)).

Example layout (grails-app/views/layouts/test.gsp):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title><g:layoutTitle/></title>
      <g:layoutHead/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="thecontent">
         <g:layoutBody/>
      </div>
      <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
      <!-- WANT DECORATED PAGE RESOURCES TO BE INCLUDED HERE -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Example gsp (grails-app/views/test.gsp):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="layout" content="test"/>
      <title>The Title</title>
      <asset:stylesheet src="thispageonly.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="helloworld">
         Hello World
      </div>
      <asset:javascript src="thispageonly.js"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

The resulting decorated page (ignoring asset-pipeline bundling/etc) works for stylesheet (since it's in head) but fails for javascript:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name="layout" content="test"/>
      <title>The Title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/thispageonly.css?compile=false"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="thecontent">
         <div id="helloworld">
            Hello World
         </div>
         <!-- *** NOT WHERE I WANT THIS *** -->
         <script src="/assets/thispageonly.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
      </div>
      <script src="/assets/application.js?compile=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Currently the only way I can get this to work is to use g:applyLayout and g:pageProperty:

```
<!-- grails-app/views/layouts/test2.gsp -->
<html>
   <head>
      <title><g:layoutTitle/></title>
      <g:layoutHead/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="thecontent">
         <g:layoutBody/>
      </div>
      <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
      <g:pageProperty name="page.javascript"/>
   </body>
</html>


<!-- grails-app/views/test2.gsp -->
<g:applyLayout name="test2">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The Title</title>
      <asset:stylesheet src="thispageonly.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="helloworld">
         Hello World
      </div>
      <content tag="javascript">
         <asset:javascript src="thispageonly.js"/>
      </content>
   </body>
</html>
</g:applyLayout>
```

But this departure from meta tag seems overly complicated (plus I'm not clear whether the poorly documented g:pageProperty will be supported as-is in future upgrades).  What's the best **long-term** way of doing this?

Comment: use resource tag and <r:layoutResources/>

Comment: @john, I would like to stick with the asset-pipeline plugin for now...for [a number of reasons](https://github.com/bertramdev/asset-pipeline/wiki/Why-asset-pipeline-over-grails-resources-plugin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of sitemesh to control object placement is totally a valid use case. Sitemesh isn't going anywhere and I actually use this to control sub container and layout inheritance. It didn't make sense to duplicate this built in flow control in the asset-pipeline plugin.

Another trick that is quite useful is to use the `<g:layoutHead/>` and `<g:layoutBody/>` tags , which are also quite useful.

If this is proving to be a problem, in the future, we may consider providing a mode that has this behavior. Let me know how things are going with asset-pipeline and if issues like this come up please feel free to open a ticket on github. Apparently, I need to keep an eye on stack overflow as well :)

Comment: Thanks @davydotcom; it's good to have this idea validated.  So far we are really impressed with the plugin.  It would be helpful to have a bit more documentation regarding the relation (or replacement?) of resource plugin items (like `g:layoutBody` and `g:javascript`).  Also, if you try to stick entirely with the asset-pipeline plugin, it appears the [built-in grails ajax remote functions](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#ajax) are not usable; so some documention on this as well would be helpful.

Comment: I was able to get the remoteLink ajax stuff to work perfectly without resources plugin. Could you by chance give me an example?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand how the configure the project, but here's a quick way to replicate:

Comment: 1) `create-app remoting`, 2) edit BuildConfig to add `compile ":asset-pipeline:1.5.1"` and to comment out `runtime ":jquery:1.10.2.2"` and `runtime ":resources:1.2.1"`, 3) `create-controller test`, 4) add controller method: `def helloworld() { render "Hello world!" }`, 5) create index.gsp with `<g:javascript library="jquery"/>` and `<asset:javascript src="deps_on_jquery.js"/>` in header plus `<g:remoteLink controller="test" action="hello world" update="mainContent">Say what?</g:remoteLink>` in body.

Comment: The above scenario will throw: `Class
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException    Message: No javascript provider is configured`

Answer (score 3):

FYI: This works well for me though it's a little bit ugly.

```
<!-- grails-app/views/layouts/test2.gsp -->
<html>
   <head>
      <title><g:layoutTitle/></title>
      <g:layoutHead/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="thecontent">
         <g:layoutBody/>
      </div>
      <asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
      <asset:deferredScripts/>
   </body>
</html>

<!-- grails-app/views/test2.gsp -->
<g:applyLayout name="test2">
<html>
   <head>
      <title>The Title</title>
      <asset:stylesheet src="thispageonly.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="helloworld">
         Hello World
      </div>
      <asset:script src="${assetPath(src: 'thispageonly.js')}" type="text/javascript" />
   </body>
</html>
</g:applyLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

IGNORE THIS ANSWER, see the comment below by the `asset-pipeline` creator about how this already exists in the asset-pipeline plugin as `<asset:script>`.

OLD ANSWER:

Sitemesh makes my head hurt, and as far as I can tell, the solution using `g:layoutHead` and `g:layoutBody` tags isn't something that'd let you collect a bunch of different javascript snippets and emit them all in a single block.

The application I've recently started working on pretty heavily leveraged the `r:script` tag, and would use it multiple times within a single gsp page (on various included templates).

How I'm planning to solve this in my app is with a taglib that just does pretty much what the `r:script` tag did.  Gather up any deferred javascript snippets and emit it where the user asks for it to be emitted.

Here's a sample taglib that can do this:

```
class DeferTagLib {
    static namespace = 'defer'
    static defaultEncodeAs = [emitScript: 'raw']  // we actually want to inject javascript :)

    private static JAVASCRIPT_DEFER_PROPERTY = "__defer__javascript"

    protected String removeJavascript() {
        try {
            return getJavascript()
        } finally {
            getRequest().removeAttribute(JAVASCRIPT_DEFER_PROPERTY)
        }
    }

    protected String getJavascript() {
        return getRequest().getAttribute(JAVASCRIPT_DEFER_PROPERTY)
    }

    protected void appendJavascript(String javascript) {
        String currentValue = getJavascript() ?: ""
        getRequest().setAttribute(JAVASCRIPT_DEFER_PROPERTY, currentValue + javascript)
    }

    // For gathering script tags in your gsp files and emitting them in the footer of the layout
    // A replacement for the r:script tag that came with Resources, but is not in the asset-pipeline plugin
    def script = { attrs, body ->
        appendJavascript(body())
    }

    // Used in the layout to emit all the script that has been deferred so far in the footer of the page
    // A replacement for the <r:layoutResources/> tag that emitted javascript in the footer
    // (the 2nd time it was called, kind of confusing...)
    def emitScript = { attrs ->
        out << "<script>${removeJavascript()}</script>"
    }
}
```

Then, in my gsp pages/fragments, I can just replace any previous calls to `r:script` with `defer:script`:

```
<defer:script>
    // this is before
</defer:script>

... maybe another template that's included ...

<defer:script>
    alert("foo!");
</defer:script>

...  later

<defer:script>
    // after
</defer:script>
```

And in my layout, at the bottom I can just do this

```
<html>
  <head>
     .... shared head stuff ....
    <g:layoutHead/>
  </head>

  <body>
    .... body stuff before layout
    <g:layoutBody/>
    .... other body stuff after layout
    <defer:emitScript/>
  </body>
</html>
```

That'll end up creating a section after the body that looks like

```
    ... the actual body from the gsp

    <script>
      // this is before ...
      alert("foo!");
      // after
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since the original writing of this stack overflow issue asset-pipeline has implemented a similar deferred. Please check the documentation on Deferred Scripts: http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#organization

Comment: <asset:script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("Hello World 2");
</asset:script>

Then render the output with: <asset:deferredScripts/>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your requirement.
In my project, I needed to move all JavaScript files to Footer.
I moved "layout Resources" tag from Header to Footer and it worked fine.

```
<footer class="clear">
    <r:layoutResources>
</footer>
```